# Start UIView at the difference of 1 pixel of statusbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autoresize, iphone-x

Targeting different iPhone devices like iPhone X & iPhone 8. I want to start my ***UIView*** just at the difference of 1px from status bar using ***autoresizing***. I was able to fix this thing by starting ***UIView*** y-axis 21px before iPhone X. How can i achieve this thing dynamically so that ***UIView*** always started after staus bar on all iphone's.

On iPhone 8 plus it look fine

[image]

On iPhone X 1px difference is not seen because view stared from top

[image]

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Using Autoresizing i want to achieve this. please see the images

Answer (score 2):

**Update for iPhone X**

Previously all iPhone devices have a status bar height of 20pt. But on iPhone X, it's 44pt. So be careful when implementing your UI.

if you want to update the UI in mainthread or call in viewWillAppear.

```
CGFloat getstatusBarHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;
CGRect modifyFrame = your1PxFrame.frame ;
modifyFrame.origin.y =  getstatusBarHeight ;
your1PxFrame.frame = modifyFrame;
```

Comment: Thanks brother. i was just want to learn about autoresizing if that could be possible. if not achieved with autoresize i will use the code :)

Comment: @Ali - some time we need to override the UI with the help of code, in my knowledge in here you can't set directly in Storyboard

Answer (score 2):

You should use autolayout!

With `autolayout and xcode 9` you can manage it like Below !

Take UIView in your storyboard or xib of iphone 7 or 8 !

Then dran and drop `UIView`(your view for which you want one pixel space) on it.

Put it like it's `y` become `21 pixel`.

then give top constraint from `safe area` to that view, and give other require constraints like leading, trailing fixed height etc.

Refer below screenshots for better understanding!

[image]

and the results are :

iPhone 8 plus:

[image]

iPhone X:

[image]

Comment: my bro ? is related to autoresizing not autolayout bro

Comment: yeah that's why I wrote in my answer that you should use autolayout! If questioner will use autolayout then this is best way to manage! @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Lion Application was developed with autoresizing. if i change it to autolayout it need lot of time. thats why i asked for autoresizing. Thanks for your response

Comment: if you want to continue with auto-resizing then you have to manage it's frame by code as per device! for that you should refer @Anbu.Karthik's answer! because with auto-resizing, I don't think that you can manage your need without code!